# using javascript to get facebook user data in facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All I want is to use `alert` to display the name of the logged in user and prompt the user to login if not logged in.
Please help, I've been online for about 4 hrs not getting the facebook graph api
this is the code from facebook.com
i do not know exactly how to manipulation this code. i have tried to add three lines towards the end...

```
<script>
function statusChangeCallback(response){
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {
testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
} else {
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
}
}

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button. See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
});
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : '1608304139394721',
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true, // parse social plugins on this page
version : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
});
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ='Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
name=response.name;
alert(name);
});
}
</script>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

I added these 2 lines to the code above but it doesn't even login. Also, it doesn't alert the user's name.

```
name=response.name;
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid and works fine, in `JavaScript` code is being executed line after line while it stops executing whenever there's an error(s) on the current line which is being executed, your error is:
[image: There's no elements in your DOM with <code>status</code> id attribute]

as you can in your code your `alert(name)` comes after that line which occurred that error 
[image: There's no elements in your DOM with <code>status</code> id attribute]

**Solution**

pretty simple add an element (`div`) with id `status` to your document to avoid that error

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

or use jQuery as a DOM selector